# Existence of solution to linear fractional equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

We consider the equation

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\lambda_j}{x-x_j} =i$$

where $\lambda_j>0$ and $x_j$ are real distinct numbers.

I want to show that if $\lambda_k$ is small compared to the distance of all $x_j$ from $x_k$ then there exists a solution $x\approx x_k- i y_k$  to this equation in the neighbourhood of $x_k.$

**Heuristic argument:**

Let $x=x_k - i y_k$ by multiplying the equation with $(x-x_k),$ we find

$$ \lambda_k - \sum_{j=1, j \neq k}^n \frac{i y_k\lambda_j}{x_k-x_j-i y_k} =y_k.$$

Now, if $x_k-x_j$ is large, then the sum is small and we can choose $y_k\approx \lambda_k.$

However, this argument is (obviously) non-rigorous.

Can we make it rigorous?

Comment: $y_k = 0 + \lambda_k + _ \lambda_k + \cdots$

Comment: This is correct (and trivial). When all $\lambda_j$ are small the LHS is small everywhere except small neighborhoods of $x_k$. To each of these neighborhoods apply Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko sorry, but for the sake of understanding. How is this theorem applied now? What are the holomorphic functions $f,g$ one would consider?- If you think it is off-topic I will close the question also, but I would appreciate an answer very much. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko the OP only assumes $\lambda_k$ to be small-

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I now received two answers and both of them seem to rely not only on distances $x_j-x_k$ but on all the parameters $\lambda_j$ as well. That's nice, but not what I asked for. Was the way you intended to apply Rouch\'e's theorem able to avoid that problem?

Comment: @J. Doe: I wrote the estimate which does not depend on the rest of $\lambda_j$.

Comment: @J.Doe: You should mark Alexandre Eremenko's answer as the accepted one then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a "real" method proof:

Without loss of generality, assume $k = 1$. You are equivalently looking for the roots of

$$ P(x, \eta) = \eta \prod_{j > 1} (x - x_j) + \sum_{\ell > 1} \lambda_\ell \prod_{j \neq \ell} (x - x_j) - i \prod_{j} (x - x_j) $$

where we wrote $\eta$ for $\lambda_1$. (We consider $\lambda_\ell$ and all $x_j$ to be fixed.)

Now allow $\eta$ to be a parameter in $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$.

For $\eta = 0$, by inspection $P(x_1, 0) = 0$. The derivative

$$ \partial_\eta P(x_1,\eta) = \prod_{j > 1} (x_1-x_j) \cdot \mathrm{Id}$$

is non-critical. So by implicit function theorem for all sufficiently small $\eta$ there exists a solution close to $x_1$.

Comment: Smallness bound of your $\eta$ depends on $x_j$ and the rest of $\lambda_j$. Was not the question about $\eta$ depending on $x_j$ only (but not on the rest of $\lambda_j$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I dunno. If the OP can clarify that'd be great!

Comment: see my answer. I made the estimate independent on the rest of $\lambda_j$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: thanks! That's a very nice answer. I +1'd it.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the comment by Alexandre Eremenko (and assuming $\lambda_j$ small for $j=k$ only).

Let us rewrite the equation in the form
$$
\underbrace{\prod_{j=1}^n (x-x_j) + i \sum_{j\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \setminus\{k\}} \lambda_j \prod_{s\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \setminus \{j\}} (x-x_s)}_{f(x)} + \underbrace{i \lambda_k \prod_{s\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \setminus \{k\}} (x-x_s)}_{g(x)} = 0.
$$

Choose $r>0$ sufficiently small so that $f(x) \ne 0$ for $x\in\partial B_r(x_k)$. Then $\min_{x\in \partial B_r(x_k)} |f(x)| = m > 0$. On the other hand if $\lambda_k$ is sufficiently small then $|g(x)| < m$ for all $x \in \partial B_r(x_k)$. Since $f(x_k)=0$ it remains to apply [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Comment: This is not wgat the question asks for, it only assumes $\lambda_k$ to be small.

Comment: @Tokoyo good point, I've updated the answer to handle the case when $\lambda_j$ is small only for $j=k$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an estimate that does not depend on $\lambda_j,j\geq 2$.

Lemma. Consider an equation $$\epsilon+az+(b+\phi(z))z^2=0,$$
 where $\epsilon>0$, $|a|\geq 1$ and  $b$, are complex constants, and
$\phi$ is analytic, $|\phi|<|b|/10.$ Then there exists a solution $|z|\leq 10\epsilon$.

Proof. If $|b|\leq |a|/(5\epsilon)$, apply Rouche to $|z|\leq2\epsilon/|a|$. The dominant term is $az$. If $b>|a|/(5\epsilon)$, apply Rouche to
$|z|\leq10\epsilon$. The dominant term is $(b+\phi)|z^2|$ now.

To apply this lemma, write your equation
$$\frac{\epsilon}{z}+\sum_2^n\frac{\lambda_k}{z-z_k}=i$$
which we bring to the form given in the lemma by
writing the sum minus $i$ in the form $a+(b+\phi(z))z$ and mulpiplying on $z$. So
$$a=-\sum_2^n\frac{\lambda_k}{z_k}-i,$$
(we have $|a|\geq 1$ because the sum is real).
$$b=-\sum_2^n\frac{\lambda_k}{z_k^2},$$
and $\phi$ is what remains. I used the identity
$$\frac{1}{z-w}=-\frac{1}{w}-\frac{z}{w^2}-\frac{z^2/w^3}{1-z/w},$$
in which I set $w=z_k$ and then add.

Now estimate $\phi$, assuming that $|z|/|z_k|<1/20$
for all $k\geq 2$.
$$|\phi(z)|=\sum_2^n\lambda_k\left|\frac{z/z_k^3}{1-z/z_k}\right|< \frac{1}{10}\sum_2^n\lambda_k/|z_k^2|<|b|/10.$$
It is important here that all $\lambda_j$ are positive.